# Custom folder and namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to use a custom folder with a namespace for certain classes in my rails project.

Essentially, what I'm building is a giant service, so technically I can move it there if I need to (though I would like to not do that). But either way, my classes aren't autoloading. 
my file structure is:

```
app/
  namespace/
      namespace.rb
      features/
        main_feature.rb # class Namespace::MainFeature
        some_feature.rb # class Namespace::SomeFeature < Namespace::MainFeature
      workers/
        a_worker.rb
```

I also load the files in my application:

```
config.paths.add File.join('app', 'namespace'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'namespace', '*')]
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/namespace/**/')
```

But I'm still getting `NameError: uninitialized constant`

What's the best way to achieve this?

EDIT:
My issue is actually that the class is only found the second time I call it in `rails console`
So

```
    [1] pry(main)> MyNamespace::Feature
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Feature, expected /Users/.../app/my_namespace/features/feature.rb to define it
from /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@pop2/gems/activesupport-5.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:511:in `load_missing_constant'
[2] pry(main)> MyNamespace::Feature
=> MyNamespace::Feature
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have the easiest time if your module structure will reflect folder structure (excluding the first level of folder, the one directly under `/app`).

```
app/
  namespace/
      namespace.rb # class Namespace
      features/
        main_feature.rb # class Features::MainFeature
        some_feature.rb # class Features::SomeFeature < Features::MainFeature
```

With this, you don't need to do any load path customization (which can certainly backfire).

> Because I would like everything to be in the `Namespace::`

Easy, just add another folder level

```
app/
  namespace/
    namespace.rb # class Namespace
    namespace/
      features/
        main_feature.rb # class Namespace::Features::MainFeature
        some_feature.rb # class Namespace::Features::SomeFeature < Namespace::Features::MainFeature
```

Comment: I was hoping I didn't have to do that. Because I would like everything to be in the `Namesspace::`